# What is really XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was reading about Jasmine over [here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/ajax.html) , which states:

> When you want to mock out all ajax calls across an entire suite, use
>   install() in a beforeEach. Because jasmine-ajax stubs out the global
>   XMLHttpRequest for the page, you’ll want to uninstall() in an
>   afterEach so specs or setup that expect to make a real ajax request
>   can.

I'm relatively new to js side, I wonder whats exactly `XMLHttpRequest` is?

If I'm doing something like this in jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

then how come `$.ajax` is related with `XMLHttpRequest`. And they meant by *global* `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: $.ajax is build around XMLHttpRequest and uses it at the end... A lot of jQuery methods are facades of native javascript methods...

Answer (score 0):

The [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) (XHR) is a method to get HTTP response from a server using JavaScript. Even though it's name has XML, don't get fooled - It works every type of data.

Since jQuery is a library, it uses JavaScript methods like  XHR. It's a pretty old system, but it is supported by most browsers except IE5 and IE6 (You need to use the ActiveXObject).

It goes like this,

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", true);
xhttp.send();
```

```html
<p>Check the console below for the result</p>
```